# How can I order a queryset by many to many related objects value?

Tags: python, django

I have a queryset containing `Book` objects.

`Book` has a m2m relationship to `Author`.

I want to order the books that are in the queryset by the name of the first author (authors would be sorted alphabetically so the first one would be the one whose last name comes first in the alphabet).

I guess it would be something about aggregation but I cannot seem to find what would be the right solution.

I have tried

`books_qs.annotate(first_author=Min('author__lastname')).order_by('first_author')`

but of course it is not the right type so I get faced with `ValueError: could not convert string to float: Folland`.

How should I go about this?

edit: Django 1.4.2 + MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Of course you'll get a `ValueError` because you're passing a string to `Min` whereas it takes float.

That is, if your `Author` model has, say, `age = models.FloatField()`, you can pass `age` as an argument to `Min`, like: `Min('age')` but you can't pass a string, in your case, `lastname`.

I don't exactly understand your question. But if you want to order anything in your Django models, I guess easiest way would be by doing this with `class Meta`

```
class Author(models.Model):
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # other fields ...

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['lastname']

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    book_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # other fields ...

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['book_name']
```

All the authors will be sorted alphabetically as per their last name and all the books will be sorted alphabetically as per their name.

Comment: Yes, that's what I wrote in my question (for the float thing).
I want the books to be ordered by author name. Say book1 has authors 'Doe', 'Simons', book2 has author 'Clark' and book3 has authors 'Webster', 'Albert. I want the order to be [book3, book2, book1] as the ordered authors would be ['Albert', 'Clark', 'Doe'].